# Using Delegates in multiple view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

I am using multiple view controllers and trying the link the UITextfield in one view controller to the label in another view controller using delegate.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;

}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2nd.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",txtField.text]
    [txtField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

ViewController2nd.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2nd : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
}

@end
```

ViewController2nd.m

```
#import "ViewController2nd.h"

@interface ViewController2nd ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2nd

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

The error i get is:

Use of undeclared identifier lbl in Viewcontroller.m

Not sure how to solve this problem. Need some guidance.. Thanks...

Comment: I think you have declared `lbl`in `ViewController2nd` so if you want to use it in `ViewController` than you have to do that with the object of `ViewController2nd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have scope/excess of `ViewController2nd`'s `IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;` in `ViewController` for this you need custom delegates, a `ViewController` a delegate of `ViewController2nd` and pass data back. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5244830/593709) for more details.

Comment: i added this: #import "ViewController2nd.h" in viewcontroller

Comment: @lakesh may you understand delegate is mistake.

Comment: @lakesh Its fine that you have imported view, but you have to initialize object of `ViewController2nd` and with that object, you can use `lbl`.

Comment: how do i do that? meaning to say i have to type IBOutlet UILabel *lbl; again in viewcontroller.m?

Comment: @lakesh: buddy, you didn't tell further details, what you trying to do, what is the flow of your app? is ViewCont2 is presented first and then VC1 presented or viceversa ?

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `lbl` is done in the wrong class.Post the     `IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;`
 within the interface of `viewcontroller.h`

incase if you want the use of variable from other class change the code to

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;
   ViewController2 *viewController2;

}
@property(nonatomic,retain)ViewController2 *viewController2;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2nd.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize viewcontroller2;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    viewController2.lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",txtField.text]
    [txtField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

ViewController2nd.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2nd : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOUTlet UILabel *lbl;
@end
```

ViewController2nd.m

```
#import "ViewController2nd.h"

@interface ViewController2nd ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2nd
@synthesize lbl;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is correct

There is no element in ViewController as lbl :)

You have to use  ViewController2nd object to access its instance properties

[Here is](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html) a place to start for object oriented programming with Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to init object of `ViewController2nd`.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
ViewController2nd *objeView2nd = [[ViewController2nd alloc]init];
objeView2nd.lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",txtField.text]
[txtField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

And one more thing, `lbl` of `ViewController2nd` must have to be `@property` and `@synthesize`. Without that, you can't access `lbl`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Singleton Class to pass data back and forth. For example the appDelegate class is the singleton class. You can use shared instance of that class to pass data back and forth.

Example:

```
      Step 1: 

             yourAppDelegate.h

             @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *txtLabelText;


             yourAppDelegate.m

             @synthesize txtLabelText;


      Step 2:

            viewController1.m

            #import viewController1.m
            #import yourAppDelegate.m

            -(void)viewDidLoad{

                 UILabel *txtLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,100,20)];

                  txtLabel.text = @"Rebel Yell";

                  yourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (yourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

                  appDelegate.txtLabelText = txtLabel.text;                

               }



     Step 3:

                  viewController2.m

                  #import viewController2.m
                  #import yourAppDelegate.m

                  -(void)viewDidLoad{

                      yourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (yourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

                      NSLog(@"Passed UILabel Text from viewController 1 %@", appDelegate.txtLabelText);

                     }
```

Instead of only relying on appDelegate class, I would recommend you to make a custom singleton class and use shared instance of that class.

Hope this would help you clear some doubts