# Sending variable to one xib to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

I have the classes.

```
@interface USSAppController : NSObject
{
    USSWindowController *windowController;
}

-(IBAction)startLesson:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)endLesson:(id)sender;

@end



@implementation USSAppController

-(IBAction)startLesson:(id)sender
{

isLesssonRunning = true;

if(isLesssonRunning)
{       
    windowController = [[USSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Lesson"];

    [windowController showWindow:self];
}
}

-(IBAction)endLesson:(id)sender
{
[windowController close];
}

@end
```

I was wondering if i could pass one variable from one class that to another when the window is created on button press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass variable data from one nib to another, you can always rely on delegation.

Here's a simple answer

[using-delegates-in-multiple-view-controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008965/using-delegates-in-multiple-view-controllers/13024037#13024037)

Comment: @joshuaBlevins Kindly do me a favour and upvote the answer in the the link provided as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom init method in USSWindowController which initializes the windowNibName and set the variable which you are passing.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName variable:(NSString)*var1
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName];
    if (self) {
        self.<instance variable> =  var1;

    }

    return self;
}
```